# In the Google AIY for Pi project make google_auth_authlib.flow visible to Python 3

Tags: python

The Google AIY project for Raspberry Pi works great out of the box.

When trying to use their libraries, scripts and code templates in a custom project, however, I hit a bump. My project has the same/similar directory structure and has their `aiy` folder in its `src` folder.

When my custom voice recognition program tries to import cloudspeech I get this error that `google_auth_authlib.flow` could not be imported.

This file is imported by the helper file `aiy/assistant/auth_helpers.py`.

Since that file and its parent and grandparent directories are identical between the AIY example repo and my project, I'm wondering what/where I need to install and import a related Google library.

To my knowledge the virtual environment of my custom project is a superset of the Google AIY virtualenv, but I suppose I must be missing something somewhere?

To make matters more interesting, if I go to the `aiy/assistant` directory on a command line with my custom projects virtualenv active, I can run

```
python auth_helpers.py
```

and it runs without any errors. Very strange.

Comment: Could you post your code? Specifically your import statements?